# Filling a DataTable and Losing First Row

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, odbc, oledb

Hey so I'm using the OleDB driver to query a CSV file and then load it up into a datatable. No matter what I do, though, it always skips the first row. Here's what I've got:

```
string connStr = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" +
            "Dbq=C:/test;Extensions=csv,txt";


OdbcConnection objCSV = new OdbcConnection(connStr);
objCSV.Open();

OdbcCommand testCmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from test.csv", objCSV);

OdbcDataAdapter testDA = new OdbcDataAdapter(testCmd);

DataTable testDT = new DataTable();

testDA.Fill(testDT);
```

So looking at some sample data like this:

```
"IDX", "FirstName", "LastName", "Email" 
"340", "John", "Smith", "test@test.com"
"341", "Johnny", "Smithee", "test@test.com"
```

I always only get 1 record, losing the first no matter how many records are in there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try telling the provider that there is a header row, like this:

```
string connStr = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" +
        "HDR=Yes;Dbq=C:/test;Extensions=csv,txt";
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually found out my problem was with misformatted csv data, I concatenated the headers for my question but the final header was missing an ending quote so it through everything off. Nonetheless I didn't know about the HDR and that actually proves useful for me so thanks!